# Force run of @Ignore'd JUnit test using Maven command line

Tags: maven, junit

I have a JUnit test with an @Ignore attribute, for example -

```
public class HealthCareGov
{
    @Test
    @Ignore
    public void performancetest()
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

In most IDEs (IntelliJ for example) I can forcefully run this test by selecting the method name even though there is an @Ignore attribute.  I'm guessing Eclipse also allows this?

However, when I try to do the same behavior in Maven by executing the following -

```
mvn -Dtest=HealthCareGov#performancetest test
```

It appears that Maven skips the test.  This is the output -

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running HealthCareGov
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.032 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
```

What Maven command line can I use to force the execution of this test to reproduce the behavior that my IDE produces?  Modifying the Java source code is not an option.

Answer (score 8):

This can be added to the test.

```
@IfProfileValue(name="test-profile", value="IntegrationTest")
public class PendingChangesITCase extends AbstractControllerIntegrationTest {
    ...
}
```

To select the tests to be executed just add the value to the profile for executing the integration tests.

```
<properties>
    <test-profile>IntegrationTest</test-profile>
</properties>
```

Also, you can use the command line to set the test-profile variable:

```
mvn -Dtest-profile=IntegrationTest
```

Comment: For sake of completeness.. 
This needs spring-test jar included and the following annotations 
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@IfProfileValue(name="test-profile", value="IntegrationTest")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "<your-spring.xml>")

Comment: Is there any solution that doesn't involve pulling in Spring?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of overriding the `@Ignore` annotation, I did the following:

- Name your test that you wish to only run from the command-line outside of the standard maven test runner nomenclature ([surefire](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) or [failsafe](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)).  This will ensure that your test does not get picked up by the regular maven lifecycle test execution.
- Write your test as normal, to include annotations for your framework on test methods.
- When you wish to run your test, just include it manually by feeding it as a parameter to the runner.

  `-Dtest=Foo     # for surefire`

  `-Dit.test=Foo  # for failsafe`

This will force you to manually specify the test via a command-line argument when you want to run it, but omit the test otherwise.

Comment: The best solution in my opinion. Spring-independent, as requested by @RikkiGibson. Thank you.